# Do spells that have range originating from the caster start in a grid intersection or the center of his square?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, area-of-effect

The rules say:

> **The point of origin of a spell is always a grid intersection.**  *PHB, p.175*

Fireburst, for example, "extends" 10 feet radius around the caster. But if you count from a grid intersection, the caster cannot be in the center of the spell. Is this intended or is there an exception to the rule cited above?

Comment: There are different views on this one, see this https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131652/what-is-the-actual-area-of-emergency-force-sphere question relating to Pathfinder and a spell with 5' radius centred on the caster but same issue.

Comment: Is this question different from [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117568/8610) or is it a duplicate? If it's supposed to be different, could it use a different example (i.e. *lightning bolt*)?

Comment: Concerning the rules content it is essentially the same question, but the title of the other question is a bit misleading as this problem does not only concern emanations. *Fireburst* for example is a burst. Maybe that question could be edited?

Comment: Edited the question to make clear the point is not about emanations, but about spells originating from the caster. By the way, there are also emanations (e.g. Alarm) that do not originate from the caster.

Comment: Although this question may not be a duplicate—and I'm tempted to vote to reopen—, can this question clarify why its answers will be different from those [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117568/8610)? After all, an "emanation spell functions like a burst spell" (*PH* 175).

Comment: No, the answers won't be different. It is probably sufficient to link the two questions, only to ensure that people find the answers.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding and experiences the radius is formed from the out side edges of the square and not from the middle of it (or the caster). So if you use "Globe of invulnerability" it will take up two squares on each side from the square you are standing on and not from you as the caster.

Comment: This would at least a kind of ruling that combines counting from a grid intersection and centering the spell on the caster. My concern is that this kind of counting is nowhere specified in the rules.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you, some of the rules are left very broad and are usually left to you and you party to ask the DM when the situation arrives.